# Using an if else statment in a reactive function for a Shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, reactive-programming, reactive

I am trying to use an if else statement inside a reactive function to output a dataset based on a user input which is a selection in a drop down menu. But it appears I am always getting the "else" output no matter what I select. Can someone please help? Thanks in advance!

```
 extract_name <- function(v1) {
        deparse(substitute(v1))
    }

 plotly_data <- reactive({
        
        if (grepl("fdr", extract_name(input$fsChoice)) == TRUE) {
        
            edited_data <- fs_data %>%
                dplyr::select(region, hemi, metric, input$fsChoice) %>%
                dplyr::filter(metric == input$metric) %>%
                dplyr::filter(hemi == input$hemi) %>%
                dplyr::filter(noninput$fsChoice > 1.30103)
            
        }
        
        else {
            
            edited_data <- fs_data %>%
                dplyr::select(region, hemi, metric, input$fsChoice) %>%
                dplyr::filter(metric == input$metric) %>%
                dplyr::filter(hemi == input$hemi)
        }
        
        return(edited_data)
        
        }
    )
```

Comment: `== TRUE` in `if` is redundant. What is `extract_name` function ? Have you tested it outside shiny app to make sure it behaves as expected ?

Comment: Hi Ronak! I have edited the question to include that function. I have tested it outside and it does work!

Answer (score 0):

`deparse(substitute(...))` behaves differently when you pass a variable to it.

```
extract_name <- function(v1) {
  deparse(substitute(v1))
}

var <- "abc"
extract_name("abc")
#[1] "\"abc\""
extract_name(var)
#[1] "var"
```

In this case, I don't think you need `extract_name` function. Try using `input$fsChoice` directly.

```
plotly_data <- reactive({
        if (grepl("fdr",input$fsChoice)) {
        
            edited_data <- fs_data %>%
                dplyr::select(region, hemi, metric, input$fsChoice) %>%
                dplyr::filter(metric == input$metric) %>%
                dplyr::filter(hemi == input$hemi) %>%
                dplyr::filter(noninput$fsChoice > 1.30103)
            
        }
        else {
            edited_data <- fs_data %>%
                dplyr::select(region, hemi, metric, input$fsChoice) %>%
                dplyr::filter(metric == input$metric) %>%
                dplyr::filter(hemi == input$hemi)
        }
        return(edited_data)
        }
    )
```

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work. I got the error: 

Warning: Error in : Problem with `filter()` input `..1`.
ℹ Input `..1` is `noninput$fsChoice > 1.30103`.
x object 'noninput' not found
  135: <Anonymous>

Comment: Well, sorry the error does not seem to be related to my changes in the code. `object 'noninput' not found` at least confirms that my code works and it is failing in this line `dplyr::filter(noninput$fsChoice > 1.30103)`. I cannot test it further since you did not provide a reproducible example and I don't know what `noninput` is.